# How i can add event to google calender with google api

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make an input form where user can add event details. User should be able to give their Google email and password in order to add an event to Google calender.

Any help please?

I have tried the below:

```
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Test Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Testing');
$event->setVisibility('public');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2014-09-28T10:00:00.000-05:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2014-09-28T10:30:00.000-05:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($createdEvent);
```

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: $event = new Google_Event();
        $event->setSummary('Test Appointment');
        $event->setLocation('Testing');
        $event->setVisibility('public');
        $start = new Google_EventDateTime();
        $start->setDateTime('2014-09-28T10:00:00.000-05:00');
        $event->setStart($start);
        $end = new Google_EventDateTime();
        $end->setDateTime('2014-09-28T10:30:00.000-05:00');
        $event->setEnd($end);
        $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($createdEvent);

Comment: thing is i want to use user gmail id and paasword to add data to thier calender via web like Zend do

Comment: Please edit your question so its easily readable

Comment: But i just saw that the api is deprecated so i was trying to use api V3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Oauth2 if you want to be able to access user's calendars. Check out https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth